# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, selenium, iceweasel

Hi I'm on my Raspberry Pi, and using Python 3 with Selenium 3.4.2, and am running into a problem making selenium work with Iceweasel.

From this block of code

```
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/pi/Desktop/geckodriver")
```

I'm getting this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/pi/Desktop/geckodriver")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Versions:

- Selenium 3.4.2
- Python 3
- Iceweasel 45.9.0esr-1~deb8u1

Comment: Which version the `geckodriver` is?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (as of 2 weeks ago) version 45 if Iceweasel is not supported by selenium. (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/728).

From the linked issue in that thread (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884), it appears that the more recent versions of Firefox are supported in the 3.4.0 release of selenium.